# Possible to Hide Mac Partition When in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, windows-vista, partitioning

I've found out that if I install Windows 7 and use the Snow Leopard Boot Camp drivers (Which I need for the graphics chipset drivers.), the Mac partition appears and is read-only. I'm quite concerned about this, because if my Windows partition is infected with malware, it could be a possibility that the hackers could take data from my Mac partition, even if it was read-only. In XP, the drivers used to not be able to view/read-only the Mac partition.

Is there any way to turn off Mac partition support while booted in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [solution on the apple support site](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11226479) suggests renaming the HFS driver file, which causes Windows to not load it. When the HFS driver isn't loaded, the partition is not visible to Windows.

Rename `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\AppleMNT.sys` to `AppleMNT.sys_orig`. As it no longer ends in `.sys`, it is no longer considered a driver file, and will not be loaded. Restart Windows, and the HFS partition will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac partition is on the same physical disk as your Windows 7 partition, you can right click it in Disk Management and choose "Change drive letter and paths" and then remove the drive letter. With no drive letter it is invisible to Windows.

Comment: Drive letters have nothing to do with access to file systems.  Drives without letter assignments can be mounted as directories in other systems or accessed via UNC paths.