# Is there a clean way to obtain exclusive access to a physical partition under Windows?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm trying, under Windows 7, to run a virtual machine with VMWare Player from an OS installed on a physical partition. However, when I boot the virtual machine, VMWare Player says that it couldn't access the physical drive for writing.

This seems to be a generally acknowledged problem in the VMWare community, as Windows Vista [introduced a compelling new security feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551353.aspx) that makes it impossible to write to a raw drive without obtaining exclusive access to it first.

I have googled the issue and found a few workarounds. However, the [clean](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1630569#1630569) [ones](http://reboot.pro/12413/) seem to only work on whole physical disks, and not on partitions.

So I would be left with [the dirty solution](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10455). In short, it meddles with the MBR to erase any trace of the partitions to use, makes Windows forget about them, then restores the MBR so we can launch the VM.

I'm not sure I want to do that. Is there a way to let VMWare acquire exclusive access to the partition without requiring me to nuke it away? What I'd be looking for, I suppose, is a way to put just partitions offline instead of whole physical drives.

---

**More infos** related to the bounty.

I have a dual-boot setup: Mac OS is my primary operating system, and I have Windows installed too. As much as I can run Windows in a virtual machine if I don't want to reboot, I'd like to be able to run Mac OS in a virtual machine when I'm under Windows.

My goal is to run my main Mac OS partition from VMWare under Windows, just like I run Windows from VMWare Fusion. (Since this is my main OS, I don't plan on patching the kernel or whatever to get it working in a virtual machine.) I created the virtual machine from VMWare Fusion (as it has the "Mac OS X Server" VM type) then moved it to Windows and modified it from VMWare Player. Seems to almost-work, as the OS gets to the loading screen and then the VM dies because it can't access `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`.

Virtual Box fails even harder, as it starts Mac OS in verbose mode and crashes very quickly (but seems to be able to access the partition), so I think it would be easier to get VMWare access my partition than to get Virtual Box to run it.

On the legal side, I'd be running one copy of Mac OS X on one Apple-labelled machine, so I'm okay.

Comment: Interesting problem. Does it work if you create a blank, unformatted partition?

Comment: @nhinkle I don't have any spare partition room I can test with on my internal drive. However, from what I read, it seems Windows will lock any partition it can recognize; and I can confirm that it will still lock those that have no mount point as well.

Comment: @zneak: I have used in the past TrueCrypt to work around Windows restrictions. As it has its own disk driver, it may be able to write to the disk. Why don't you try making the partition into a TrueCrypt virtual disk?

Comment: @harrymc I haven't tried. Do I need to encrypt my Mac OS partition?

Comment: You will need to create a TrueCrypt volume on the partition (losing all content). [This](http://dailycupoftech.com/creating-a-basic-truecrypt-volume/) might help to show how, but see also the TrueCrypt help.

Comment: @harrymc Losing all content is not an option, since my Mac OS partition is my primary partition. Also, if TrueCrypt makes it impossible to boot Mac OS natively from it, it's not much better.

Comment: I am a bit lost: Are you first booting into Windows? Isn't Mac OS in a virtual machine? Maybe you could clarify the post. My suggested TrueCrypt solution was based on the idea of booting Windows, mounting TrueCrypt disk and then starting VMware.

Comment: @harrymc I'm sorry. I have a dual-boot setup, and I'm afraid encrypting the Mac OS partition would render it unbootable (natively). I clarified the question a little (I added a paragraph under the "More Infos" subtitle).

Comment: Much clearer now : Microsoft has obviously nixed your game. I will search some more later on, but I now understand why all articles recommend using 2 disks rather than partitions. Is it important enough for you to install a 2nd hard disk?

Comment: does just toggling the "hidden" partition flag do anything for you?  long shot, but it might work

Comment: @harrymc Well, not really, and anyways it's kind of hard to find room for a second hard drive in a laptop. :/

Comment: @aking1012 I'll google that and give it a go.

Comment: @aking1012 I'd prefer a way that doesn't imply messing around with the sector 0.

Comment: okay i thought it might be acceptable because it isn't completely mangling your partition table, just toggling a flag.  it was just a thought

Comment: have you tried the sys rename mentioned in my other post: http://superuser.com/questions/213731/213756#213756

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\AppleMNT.sys to ..\"AppleMNT.sys_orig" and restart win makes windows unable to read the partition.  this might be sufficient...

Comment: @aking1012 That's kind of suboptimal, but switching the ability to read my Mac OS partition for a Mac OS virtual machine seems like an acceptable trade. I'll try it.

Comment: @aking1012 It doesn't work.

Comment: okay...sorry thought it was worth a shot

Comment: @zneak: I have edited into my answer the only possible solution I have come across.

Comment: I have set a bounty on a similar question [CreateFile: direct write operation to raw disk “Access is denied” - Vista, Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694713/341970). Could you help me?

Comment: @Ali, it turns out that it never worked for me. The answer that got the bounty received it because it was upvoted twice, but the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Excellent... :S I hope my bounty won't go to waste and we will find an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have come across only one possible solution, using the free virtual disk driver [imdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) together with devio (remote drive access and acquisition). As imdisk is a kernel driver, it might be able to write to the partition. Unfortunately, as devio works in user-mode, I am not too sure whether this approach will work for you.

devio can acquire a physical partition and publish it on the network. For example:

```
devio -r 9000 \\.\PhysicalDrive0 2
```

does publish from the first disk the second partition on TCP port 9000, and will wait for a connection on this port. Better disable the firewall while testing this, and run devio as administrator.

To define this published partition as a new and stand-alone hard disk, use :

```
imdisk -a -t proxy -o ip -f 127.0.0.1 -m R:
```

which using localhost will create a new hard disk called R which is not a partition of anything. You can now try whether you can use the pretend real hard disk R in a VMware virtual machine.

This approach is explained in detail in [Devio: Remote drive access and acquisition](http://grandstreamdreams.blogspot.com/2009/08/devio-remote-drive-access-and.html).

If this doesn't work, you will either have to :

1. Accept a dangerous solution that modifies the MBR.
2. Abandon using MacOS within Win7 as VM, using files in the Mac partition through Windows applications (with end-of-line character problems).
3. Use a Virtual File System product, such as [ELDOS Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/), although I
   doubt that this problem is worth for you a few thousand dollars.
4. Abandon Windows 7 and downgrade to XP.
5. Modify the [source of imdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/files/imdisk_source.7z) so that as a kernel driver it will create a pretend disk directly on the physical partition, without the need for devio.

Comment: If done properly, editing the MBR should not pose too big a threat.  Even if it were to become corrupted, it's not the primary OS partition, so who cares?  You can easily fix it!

Comment: @Breakthrough I think you miss the fact that both OSes are on the same disk.

Comment: @zneak: I think @Breakthrough is right - there are several programs that can save and then restore the MBR in emergency.

Comment: Also, just for the record, VMWare unfortunately can't use a virtual drive from imdisk.

Comment: That's correct, because ImDisk doesn't register correctly with the NT Mount Manager using the [IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code; it instead directly creates a symbolic link for the drive letter, and of course the kernel doesn't consider that a legitimate volume. I've tried to get it to work before, but I haven't succeeded much. (It's the same reason why you can't use an ImDisk volume for, say, mounting a VHD.)

Comment: @Lambert: imdisk already supports the syntax of PhysicalDriveX & partition, so it's half-way there. If you have already tried modifying it, I wonder what didn't work.

Comment: @harrymc: Sorry, what I said was misleading... by "try" I didn't mean that I couldn't get the program to work, but that I didn't understand the documentation well (it's hard to find info on the mount manager) and I was too lazy to look too hard. :)

Comment: @Lambert: The place to modify can probably be found by searching the code for the right API functions. Maybe @zneak will be motivated enough to do that, a very useful enhancement to imdisk. The source code isn't so very large.

Comment: @harrymc: Yeah, I could probably do it if I was determined enough to; laziness has been the main reason. Maybe I'll try it sometime, if @zneak doesn't do that. :)

Comment: @zneak: What exactly is the problem with using VMware with imdisk ?

Comment: @harrymc When I tried to select another physical drive, VMware would report immediately that it couldn't access a drive for reading, and it would stop there. I suppose it's the imdisk one it couldn't access (it didn't tell).

Comment: @zneak: It might be that imdisk doesn't support raw disk access. @Lambert may have the right idea as regarding the cause.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how desperate you are to get this working, but I would say that it's possible, with "just" two "easy" (read: brutal) steps:

1. Write a driver to bypass the restriction set by Windows, using the (semi-?)documented flag `SL_FORCE_DIRECT_WRITE`.
2. Hook the `CreateFile` and/or `WriteFile` call from VMWare using a library like [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) (I told you it was easy!) to communicate with the file manually with your driver, perhaps communicating with the driver using `DeviceIoControl`.

It actually doesn't sound that bad, if you know where to look for the information for bypassing the restrictions... I've hooked applications like Nero myself in order to examine `IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH` calls so I can make my own CD burner library, and this wouldn't be too difficult; writing a driver will be the harder part, but manageable.

---

Edit:

I'm guessing you already figured this out, but the structure you need to modify is called [FLT_IO_PARAMETER_BLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `IRP_MJ_READ`. Not sure how easy it will be, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Sounds fun. I'll look into that tomorrow.

Comment: @zneak: If you look at my answer, imdisk is an available open-source virtual disk driver, which almost does already what you want.

Comment: @Mehrdad I have a very similar problem, could you help me? [CreateFile: “Access is denied” even with Administrator privileges - Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694713/341970)